# Why does my Windows Vista PC connected to internet via an USB-tethered iPhone not share the connection?

Tags: windows-vista, tethering, ics

Our only internet connection is a tethered iPhone connected by USB to the PC, and this works well. I would like to plug an ethernet cable into the PC's network card and connect this to other devices and thus share the connection. However, when I do this the other devices can't access the internet. The iPhone's personal hotspot wifi feature is useless as is Bluetooth so how can I configure the PC to route its connection from USB to the network card?

I have tried enabling ICS but can't as there is no Sharing tab when I right-click the iPhone connection in Network Connections.

I have also looked into Virtual Router software but can't find any that works in Vista or that routes to the ethernet port rather than wifi (no wireless card in PC).

How can I share the tethered iPhone connection? Do I need a second NIC?

OS is Vista Home Premium

Comment: Which version of Vista do you have? (It may be relevant. Some of the cheaper versions of MS-Windows have some features disabled.)(amend your question with this information)

Comment: Hi Ramhound, the wifi tethering clicks off all the time and doesn't penetrate the house at all.

Comment: Hi Richard, it's home premium, if that's what you mean